# end.index does not indetify letters in a string

Tags: swift

**there's a task:**
Create a function that takes in a word and determines whether or not it is plural. A plural word is one that ends in "s"

**there's my solution:**

```
func isPlural(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    return word[word.endIndex - 1] == "s"
}
```

now it has an error

*binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index') and 'Int'
return word[word.endIndex - 1] == "s"*

Otherwise, in a case when we use an array like this:

*let x = Array(word.characters)*

task is solved

why index doesn't work with a string?

Comment: Why not simply return `word.last == "s"`? if you would like to detect uppercase as well `word.last?.lowercased() == "s"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Index` is not `Int` as elaborated in the other answers.

There is a simpler solution to determine if a string ends with a specific character

```
func isPlural(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    return word.hasSuffix("s")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution for this would be:

```
func isPlural(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    guard !word.isEmpty else { return false }
    
    return word[word.index(before: word.endIndex)] == "s"
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because Strings in Swift are indexed by the type `String.Index` and not `Int`. You've tried to treat this like an Int by doing "-1" on it, hence the error.

**More Elaboration (If Needed):**

The reason why Strings can't be indexed in Swift using `Int` has do do with how they are represented internally. A String is nothing more than a sequence of Unicode under the hood. So it's possible to have one Unicode represent one `Character` or three Unicodes represent the exact same `Character`. Using an `Int` index could cause some ambiguity with regards to indexing. To resolve this issue, `String.Index` is used.

With Arrays, there's no such ambiguity so `Int` is a type alias for `Array.Index` which is why you can use `Int` to index an `Array`

**Edit 1:**

I have added a guard statement to prevent a crash in the event of an empty String. There are more succinct ways to solve this problem obviously but I thought the above code was better to clarify the asker's confusion with String indexing

Comment: Btw this would crash with an empty string

Comment: @LeoDabus I think people could still learn something from the rest of the answer. Feel free to edit if needed

Comment: I do agree the answer does explain the issue but even as it is now it is not the correct solution. There is numerous alternatives that wouldn't crash with empty strings. If you still would like to go with this one you should add that possibility to your answer and use a guard to avoid the crash. From the docs **Parameters - A valid index of the collection. i must be greater than startIndex.**